# Internet not working on Ubuntu 14.04.01 LTS

Tags: server, internet, ethernet, ifconfig

I am unable to connect to the internet from within Ubuntu (version 14.04.01 LTS). I've tried solutions in related forum posts, but none of them have worked so far. Any help to resolve this would be really appreciated.

I can open firefox and use the internet from there, but an example of the output from ping is:

> ping: unknown host www.google.com

The output of ifconfig is:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:58:f7:74  
          inet addr:172.21.3.42  Bcast:172.21.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:90ff:fe58:f774/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:78128 errors:0 dropped:35 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16658 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:9206366 (9.2 MB)  TX bytes:2853288 (2.8 MB)
          Memory:f0000000-f0020000

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:58:f7:75  
          inet addr:172.21.10.67  Bcast:172.21.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:90ff:fe58:f775/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:61518 errors:0 dropped:30 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1359 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7464478 (7.4 MB)  TX bytes:146052 (146.0 KB)
          Memory:f0040000-f0060000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:84984 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:84984 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:9607658 (9.6 MB)  TX bytes:9607658 (9.6 MB)
```

The output from netstat -r -n is:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         172.21.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth1
172.21.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
172.21.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth1
```

The interfaces file has the following lines:

```
/etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
#auto lo eth0
#iface lo inet loopback
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static
address 172.21.3.42
netmask 255.255.0.0
gateway 172.21.0.1
#       dns-search www.google.com
dns-nameservers 172.21.3.1
```

The output from nm-tool is:

```
nm-tool

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth1  [E2] -----------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            igb
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        00:25:90:58:F7:75

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           1000 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         172.21.10.67
    Prefix:          16 (255.255.0.0)
    Gateway:         172.21.0.1

    DNS:             172.21.3.103
    DNS:             172.21.3.1


- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            igb
  State:             unmanaged
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        00:25:90:58:F7:74

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           1000 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on
```

Comment: So to clarify, Firefox works fine but ping doesn't?

Comment: which is the response of *dig www.google.com*

Comment: There are two interfaces with same IP.

Comment: Auto configuration failed
139638191867776:error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied:bss_file.c:169:fopen('/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf','rb')
139638191867776:error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib:bss_file.c:174:
139638191867776:error:0E078002:configuration file routines:DEF_LOAD:system lib:conf_def.c:199:

Comment: @MarkSmith Firefox works fine from my user account, but not from my colleagues or when using superuser

Comment: @Pilot6 can this be seen from the two identical lines in the netstat command? How can I change it? Thanks!

Comment: I want eth0 to be the default

Comment: This can be seen in `ifconfig`. I can't tell you how to fix it, because I do not know where these addresses came from? Please add full output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: Ah, sorry I realise that now, thanks. /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
#auto lo
#iface lo inet loopback

auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static
 address 172.21.3.42
 netmask 255.255.0.0
 gateway 172.21.0.1
#       dns-search www.google.com
dns-nameservers 172.21.3.1

Comment: Add it to your question please. Not here.

Comment: Why do you format it this way. Use `{ }` to format code.

Comment: @Pilot6 I've added it to the description. I put the lines with # in quotes so that they don't appear as headers

Comment: Are there quotes in this file? Anything regarding `eth1`?

Comment: @Pilot6 Good advice, this is my first time posting and I was using >, but I'll do as you suggest from now on.

Comment: And remove `eth0` after `auto lo`.

Comment: @Pilot6 Done, but I still can't ping

Comment: And what is your goal? What are you trying to setup with 2 interfaces?

Comment: OK. Do `sudo ifdown eth1`

Comment: @Pilot6 We have two ethernet cables and would eventually like to bond them for more bandwidth, but that's a challenge for another day. At the moment we just want the server to be able to connect to the internet through 1 interface.

Comment: @Pilot6 the output is: ifdown: interface eth1 not configured

Comment: Setup some other IP for `eth1`.

Comment: @Pilot6 I've set up an alternative IP for eth1. I done a network-manager restart, but ping still doesn't work.

Comment: I've editied the ifconfig output in the question to show the new output for the eth1 ip address

Comment: I've added the output from the nm-tool command. This shows that eth1 is the default. Could this be the problem? How can I change this to eth0? @Pilot6

Comment: It's working now! The problem was that eth1 was the default and pointing to the gateway address. The default needed to be eth0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

> route -n

and also `nm-tool`:

I could see that eth1 had become set as the default, and was pointing to the gateway address.
Our setup required eth0 to be the default. This was resolved using:

```
sudo ip route change to default dev eth0 via 172.21.0.1
```

where 172.21.0.1 is the gateway address.